# NameError: name 'vote' is not defined

Tags: python

I don't understand why python interpreter doesn't accept my matrix.
I've tried to change it with different types of declaration but it didn’t work.

```
x=1

vote[1][2]

for i in range(x):
    for j in range(2**x):
        vote[i][j]=False

for i in range(x):
        j=0
        state=False
        while j<2**x:
            if j%2**(i):
                state=not(state)
            vote[i][j]=state
            j=j+1

for i in range(x):
        j=0
        while j<2**x:
            print(vote[i][j], end=' ')
            j=j+1
        print('\n')
```

Comment: So what do you expect `vote[1][2]` to do? That just *references* the name, it doesn't create anything, if that is what you expected.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> vote[1][2]
> ```

Here you try to access an element from the list, but you have not created the list.  You need to create the list objects and assign it to the name `vote`.

For example:

```
vote = []
for i in range(2):
    vote.append( [None]*3 )
print( vote )
```